# Quantifying the quantum electric field for $E$-fields that are not waves

Tags: electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law

In every physicists training, an electrostatics course will show how to solve Maxwell's equations for different systems, solving for the $E$-field at different points in space.

A separate solution to Maxwell's solution for an accellerating charge shows that there is a wiggling "wave" in the far-field.

Typically to understand the electric-field in a quantum framework, we decide to quantize the fourier coefficients of the solution to Maxwell's equations. I haven't seen a treatment that deals with non-photon-electric fields. (Either by changes in time in the near-field, or static $E$-fields.)

Is there a general framework for what the quantum $E$-field looks like for static electric fields?
Do you just grab the zero frequency mode? If so, is this something that has been experimentally measured? This has been asked [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160746/), but it seems as though the asker was concerned specifically with reproducing the classical values -- and the accepted answer is very unsatisfying
as a result (essentially just saying to use a displacement operator and look at the average..).

Comment: Related: [coulomb field from qed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778026/)